# Why am I getting this error, everything looks right: "Undefined index"?

Tags: php, mysql

I am at a loss here.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting the error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/*****/public_html/newfinal/home_view.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: description in /home/****/public_html/newfinal/home_view.php on line 15
```

Here are the relevant code snippets:

PHP/ SQL

```
function get_product($product_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM prjProducts p"
            . " INNER JOIN prjCategories c"
            . " ON p.categoryID = c.categoryID"
            . " WHERE productID = :product_id";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':product_id', $product_id);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $error = $ex->getMessage();
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

PHP

```
// Set the featured product Id's in an array
$product_ids = array(3, 5, 10);

// Get an array of featured producst from the database
$products = array();
foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
    $product = get_product($product_id);
    $products[] = $product; // add the product to the array

}
```

HTML

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) :
          // Get product data
          $price = $product['price'];
          $description = $product['description'];
```

I have been banging my head at this one for a couple of hours now.  I've tried to echo the arrays, and I can print out the arrays without issue.  I'm sure it is some small formatting error that I am missing somewhere.

Comment: What are the columns you have in `prjProducts` table?

Comment: Please print your $products array and show @harlan

Comment: use var_dump($products) and print_r ($products) to see the actual data you are getting

Comment: @masterFly `productID, categoryID, productName, description, price, imgFile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First check whether you have the `price` and `description` columns in your table `prjProducts`.
2. In your `foreach ($products as $product)` loop, do a `var_dump` for `$product` and check to see whether it is an `array` or an `object`?

If it is not an array you should do `$product->price` instead of `$product['price']`.

Comment: Here is the `var_dump`: `array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["productID"]=> string(1) "3" ["categoryID"]=> string(1) "4" ["productName"]=> string(44) "Gerber Swagger Assisted Opening Pocket Knife" ["description"]=> string(125) "The Gerber Swagger assisted opening pocket knife offers a dual G-10 and Stainless steel handle for great grip and durability." ["price"]=> string(5) "39.99" ["imgFile"]=> string(16) "gerberpocket.jpg" ["categoryName"]=> string(13) "Pocket Knives" } } `

Comment: This is the var dump of products right? Not product?

Comment: That is a var_dump of $product, inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, though not the solution.  I ran a `print_r($products)` directly after the first foreach function.  It looks as if it is a three level array instead of 2.  And the second level does not have an index number?  Why would this be and how do I fix it?

Comment: So if this is the dump of single $product, $product['price'] is nit there. Because the details are inside another array. So it shoul be $product[0][price]

Comment: That as it.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy that we figured this out before your life ends :P